# Что означает super_?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ооп, npm, backend

Node_JS:

В встроенном модуле util есть функция `inherits`. 
Я знаю, что такое `super` в js, но что такое `super_`?

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor){  
    ctor.super_ = superCtor  
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {  
      constructor: {
        value:ctor,
        enumerable:false,
        writable:true,
        configurable:true
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Просто имя поля

Comment: `var obj = {}; obj.sdkhdsdshdskjdh = 1` что такое `sdkhdsdshdskjdh`?

Answer (score 2):

> Подчёркивание в начале свойства – общепринятый знак, что свойство
>   является внутренним, предназначенным лишь для доступа из самого
>   объекта и его наследников. Такие свойства называют *защищёнными*.

**Источник**: [Защищённые свойства](https://learn.javascript.ru/functional-inheritance#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

В вашем случаи подчеркивание в конце свойства, скорее всего соглашения по наименованию команды, которая писала модуль.

> В `JavaScript` существует множество разных способов наследования, классового и прототипного, фабричного и через примеси, прямого и непрямого, а так же гибриды нескольких методов. Но у `Node.js` есть его родной способ с применением `util.inherits(ChildClass, ParentClass)`.

**Источник**: [Краткая заметка про наследование в Node.js](https://habr.com/post/247325/)

Как я понял метод `inherits`, это имитация метода `Object.create` (Это мое сугубое предположение, ибо я не знаю как реализован метод `inherits`), а в свойство `ctor.super_` (`ctor - ChildClass`) присваивается функция-конструктор, или объект. Это сделано для того, что бы иметь доступ к методам этой функции, или объекта для дальнейшего использования.

**Пример:**

```js
'use strict';
 
let animal = {
  walk() {
    return "I'm walking";
  }
};
 
let rabbit = {
  __proto__: animal,
  walk() {
    console.log(this.walk);
    console.log(super.walk()); // I'm walking
  }
};
 
rabbit.walk();
```

Тут есть два метода `walk`. Допустим надо вызвать метод `walk`, который унаследован от `animal`, но так как у нас есть свой родной метод, мы этого сделать не можем, разве что так: `rabbit.__proto__.walk();`. Вот тут и приходит на выручку оператор `super`.

> Ключевое слово `super` используется для вызова функций, принадлежащих
>   родителю объекта.
>
> **Описание**
>
> В конструкторе ключевое слово `super` используется как функция,
>   вызывающая родительский конструктор. Её необходимо вызвать до первого
>   обращения к ключевому слову `this` в теле конструктора. Ключевое слово
>   `super` также может быть использовано для вызова функций родительского
>   объекта.

**Источник**: [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

**Если резюмировать:** `_` - это общепринятый знак для свойств, которые являются внутренними. Они предназначенным лишь для доступа из самого объекта и его наследников, а свойство `super_` - это имитация оператора `super` из `js`.